# Functional vs Safety / Static vs Dynamic instantiations

Tags: c++, instantiation, simulator

I'm in a situation where I think that two implementations are correct, and I don't know which one to choose.

I've an application simulating card readers. It has a GUI where you choose which serial port, and speed to use, and a play and stop button.

I'm looking for the best implementation for reader construction.

I have a `SimulatorCore` class who's living as long as my application
SimulatorCore instantiate the `Reader` class. And it will be possible to simulate multiple readers on multiple serial port.

Two possibilities:

- My `Reader` is a pointer (dynamic instantiation), I instantiate it when play button is hit, delete it when stop button is hit.
- My `Reader` is an object (static instantiation), I instantiate it in `SimulatorCore` constructor then create and call `Reader.init()` and `Reader.cleanup()` into my Reader class and call these when play and stop are being hit

I personally see the functional side, and I clearly want to use pointer, and do not have any reader instantiate if no reader are simulated.

Someone say me that I should use static instantiation (Reason : for safety, and because "it's bad to use pointer when you have choice to not use them")

I'm not familiar with them, but I think I can also use smart pointer.

**Code samples: 1st solution:**

```
class SimulatorCore
{  
    play(){reader = new Reader();};
    stop(){delete reader; reader = nullptr;};

private:
    Reader *reader;
}
```

**Code samples: 2nd solution:**

```
class SimulatorCore
{  
    play(){reader.init();};
    stop(){reader.cleanup();};

private:
    Reader reader;
}
```

The code is unstest, I've juste wite it for illustration.

What is the best solution? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally avoid performing dynamic allocation with `new` yourself, so if you were going to go with the 1st solution, you should use smart pointers instead.

However, the main question here is a question of logic. A real card reader exists in an idle state until it is being used. In the 2nd solution, what do `init` and `cleanup` do? Do they simply setup the card reader into an idle state or do they start simulating actually having a card being read? If it's the first case, I suggest that this behaviour should be in the constructor and destructor of `Reader`, and then creating a `Reader` object denotes bringing a card reader into existence. If it's the second case, then I'd say the 2nd solution is pretty much correct, just that the functions are badly named.

What seems most logical to me is something more like this:

```
class SimulatorCore
{  
    play(){reader.start();};
    stop(){reader.stop();};

private:
    Reader reader;
}
```

Yes, all I've done is change the function names for `Reader`. However, the functions now are not responsible for initialising or cleaning up the reader - that responsibility is in the hands of `Reader`'s constructor and destructor. Instead, `start` and `stop` begin and end simulation of the `Reader`. A single `Reader` instance can then enter and exit this simulation mode multiple times in its lifetime.

If you later want to extend this idea to multiple `Reader`s, you can just change the member to:

```
std::vector<Reader> readers;
```

However, I cannot know for certain that this is what you want because I don't know the logic of your program. Hopefully this will give you some ideas though.

Again, whatever you decide to do, you should avoid using `new` to allocate your `Reader`s and then also avoid using raw pointers to refer to those `Reader`s. Use smart pointers and their corresponding `make_...` functions to dynamically allocate those objects.

Comment: Really good explanation, thanks. I'll use smart pointer, I think it's the best solution, and I need to practice them ! 
The stop button actually stop the simulation, no simulation = no reader, so I think good to delete the reader.

Comment: @MoKaT Okay, if that's your logic, then that sounds okay!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use shared_ptr/unique_ptr:

```
class SimulatorCore
{  
    play(){_reader = make_shared<Reader>();};
    stop(){_reader = nullptr};

private:
    shared_ptr<Reader> _reader;
}
```

That will solve your problem right way, I guess.

Dynamic allocation gives some problems, for example, with throwing exception (there can be memory losing if between play() and stop() there will be thrown exception, for example, and stop() will never be called). Or you can just forget somewhere call stop() before destruction of SimulatorCore, it is possible if program is heavy.

If you never tried smart pointers, it is good chance to start doing it.

Comment: Thanks, I've finally use unique_ptr and it's working great. I'll accept the other answer because of the explanations, but you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly depends on how your whole program is organized, but in general, I think I would prefer the static approach, because of **responsability** considerations:

Suppose you have a separate class that handles serial communication. That class will send and receive messages and dispatch them to the reader class. A message may arrive at any time. The difference of the dynamic and static approaches is:

- With the dynamic approach, the serial class must test if the reader actually exists before dispatching a message. Or the reader has to register and unregister itself in the serial class.
- With the static approach, the reader class can decide for itself, if it is able to process the message at the moment, or not.

So I think the static approach is a bit easier and straight-forward.

However, if there is a chance that you will have to implement other, **different reader classes** in the future, the dynamic approach will make this extension easier, because the appropriate class can easily be instanciated at runtime.

So the dynamic approach offers more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, my comunication is part of my reader (as I'll maybe need multiple readers, on different serial port - USB). And I have multiple reader classes, but on another level (where I have an abstract base classe, who is my interface for instantiate different readers). Smart pointer seems perfect for this case.

Comment: I've simplified my question, but the `Reader` we speaking here is a state machine who instantiate the real reader. But it was more a functional question, than a technical one.

Comment: Ok, with the first part of this answer I tried to show an example where the "always present and valid" property of static objects are an advantage. Based on what you added here, I think I would use smart pointers, too.